# Multiplie Specific row with specific condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I want to multiple a column in pandas and replace the old value by the value computed.

Example :

```
EURUSD = 2
print(df)

           Instrument      Price,
  1         BTC/EUR        40000
  2         ETH/EUR        3000         
  3         SOL/USD        3200
  4         ADA/EUR        2.2 
  5         DOT/USD        29

)
```

If the instrument ends by "EUR", I would like to multiply the price by the exchange rate EURUSD to convert the price in USD.

The result would be :

```
print(df)

           Instrument      Price,
  1         BTC/EUR        80000
  2         ETH/EUR        6000         
  3         SOL/USD        3200
  4         ADA/EUR        4.4
  5         DOT/USD        29

)
```

I tried the following code :

```
df.loc[df["Instrument"].str[-3:] == "EUR",df["Price"]]=df["Price"]*EURUSD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
In [167]: import numpy as np

# Check whether the 'Instrument' value contains 'EUR', if TRUE then PRICE * 2, otherwise leave PRICE as is. 
In [168]: df['Price'] = np.where(df.Instrument.str.contains('EUR'), df.Price.mul(2), df.Price)

In [169]: df
Out[169]: 
  Instrument    Price
1    BTC/EUR  80000.0
2    ETH/EUR   6000.0
3    SOL/USD   3200.0
4    ADA/EUR      4.4
5    DOT/USD     29.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i have the following error message 

`df['Price'] = np.where(df.Instrument.str.contains('EUR'), df.Price.mul(2))`
  `File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in where`
`ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given`

Comment: @StefanHanssen You are typing the incomplete command. Please copy my `np.where` command properly. You are missing the last `, df.Price` there.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! it is working perfectly